# Any better source TTS package for .Net?

Tags: .net, speech, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I need to implement a Text-To-Speech (TTS) system in my C#.Net application. Now I am using C# .Net TTS package (System.Speech.Synthesis), which should be the same as the speaker in Windows. But I found this TTS sounds really weird. So I would like to ask whether there is any other options for TTS system which could speak more naturally and smooth. Preferably it is free of charge because I am not doing a commercial project.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://espeak.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [built in class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.aspx) with .NET which does this. Its much smoother than [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/). The best of all I had luck with was IBM's [viavoice](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/pervasive/viavoice.html) but I do not think its free anymore. There is [festival tts](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) which is free, but I couldn't use it in my desktop application.

The `System.Speech` is what I felt which gives the best balance between ease of use and speech quality. Viavoice sounded even better, but we had to compile the dlls  to a commandline app to integrate it as a separate process to get it run. espeak provides a built in command line app which you can run in the background.

Comment: NB: `System.Speech` is not available in mono, meaning it's not available in macOS or Linux. You can access a TTS on macOS through `Xamarin.Mac`'s `AppKit.NSSpeechSynthesizer`(for simple stuff) and `AppKit.SpeechManager` (for more advanced stuff). I don't know of anything for Linux, so you may have to roll your own wrapper around, for example, eSpeak or Festival.